# Cannot run any WSL commands/Not able to make WSL work with VS Code (Exec Format Error)

Tags: linux, windows, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, compatibility

I tried setting up VS Code with WSL, when I tried running code, I was met with a "Exec format error code", found it weird, tried to do other simpler stuff such as "notepad.exe" or any other normally accessible commands. Once again, it tries to run it and I am met with this error

```
newsofpe@DESKTOP-H6GRFEM:~$ code
/mnt/c/Users/Newso/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code: 61: /mnt/c/Users/Newso/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe: Exec format error
newsofpe@DESKTOP-H6GRFEM:~$ notepad.exe
-bash: /mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32/notepad.exe: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I am pretty sure this is not a x86/x64 compatibility error.

This is the version I am running:

Linux DESKTOP-H6GRFEM 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Jan 27 02:56:13 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Tried looking it up online and search about similar situations such as mine and am met with no solution to my problem as it is such a niche/non researched thing for the moment.

Comment: See if this helps you: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8952 and https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8151

Comment: That's fantastic. Glad you resolved this and wrote an answer. If you have the ability to accept your own answer, please do. That way, someone with the same issue can get to a resolution quicker seeing your answer. Great job!!

Comment: I have found that the solution I had found does not work, uninstalling and reinstalling only makes it work the first time after, once you reboot the wsl, everything goes back like before and I cannot run notepad.exe or anything else anymore

Comment: You might want to open an issue https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues

Comment: a specific issue has already been created: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/10363

Answer (score 4):

I solved with the script below:

```bash
sudo sh -c 'echo :WSLInterop:M::MZ::/init:PF > /usr/lib/binfmt.d/WSLInterop.conf'
sudo systemctl restart systemd-binfmt
```

Credits go to the author of the following comment https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8952#issuecomment-1568212651